# Получение value input`а при нажатии на кнопку(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, input

```
<input type="text" id="fname">
<input type="text" id="lname">
<input type="button" value="Enter" id="fsubmit">
```

Нужно получить value fname или lname вызовом функции getVal.
Пробовал

```
function getValue(e){
    console.log(e.value);
}
var fsubmit = document.getElementById("fsubmit");
fsubmit.onclick = getValue("fname");
```

Консоль выдает undefined сразу при загрузке, без нажатия.
Работает только так(на самом input`е):

```
function getValue(){
    console.log("Button clicked, value "+ this.value);
}
var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
fname.onclick = getValue;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getValue(e){
    console.log(e.value);
}
var fsubmit = document.getElementById("fsubmit");
fsubmit.onclick = getValue("fname");
```

`getValue("fname");` вызывает функцию `getValue` с параметром `"fname"` - ничего не возвращая. Таким образом, `.onclick` остается неназначеным. Внутри `getValue` ожидается, что `е` - это инпут элемент со свойством `value`, а не строка. Свойство `value` строки - `undefined`.

```
function getValue(element){
    console.log(element.value);
}
var fsubmit = document.getElementById("fsubmit");
fsubmit.onclick = function(event) { 
  getValue(document.getElementById("fname")); 
};
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что хотел. JavaScript недолго изучаю.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fsubmit = document.getElementById("fsubmit");
fsubmit.onclick = function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("fname").value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getValue() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('fname').value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onclick="$(this).val()">
<input type="text" id="lname" onclick="$(this).val()">
```